# Something like OverlayFS for s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there something like OverlayFS, but for aws s3?

Our production system stores data in aws s3.

We have several test systems. Up to now we copy all data from the production s3
to s3 of the test system.

This is slow.

It would be great if there would be something like OverlayFS, but for s3:

- Writes should go the test system
- Reads should first check if there was a write to the test system. If yes, take this.
- else (not write was done yet), then the read should go to the production system.

At the end I want a s3 API (not a file-system)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and ended up creating a fork of S3Proxy with support for an "OverlayBlobstore".

I wouldn't say that it's production-ready, and I'm not sure I'm motivated enough to ever bring it to that point but it works well enough for testing purposes.

```
$ docker run --rm -it switchmedia/s3proxy:latest \
  --publish 80:80
  --env S3PROXY_AUTHORIZATION=none \
  --env JCLOUDS_IDENTITY=$S3_ACCESS_KEY \
  --env JCLOUDS_CREDENTIAL=$S3_SECRET_KEY \
  --env JCLOUDS_PROVIDER=s3 \
  --env S3PROXY_OVERLAY_BLOBSTORE=true

$ curl -XGET localhost/bucket_name
```

**Note:** I strongly suggest you use credentials that are limited to **Read Only**. That way if there is a bug in the software, or the overlay is disabled for some reason, writes don't leak through.

[Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/switchmedia/s3proxy)
[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Switch-TV/s3proxy/tree/feature/overlay-middleware)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with a combination of [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) and [overlay fs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem):

1. Mount your prod bucket using s3fs, read-only
2. Mount your test bucket using s3fs, read and write
3. Create an overlay using the two mounted buckets, for example:

```sh
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/mnt/s3-prod,upperdir=/mnt/s3-dev,workdir=/mnt/work /mnt/merged
```

Comment: Thank you. At the end I want a s3 API, not a file-system. I updated the question to make this more clear

Comment: I tested this solution, but it was horrendously slow. I think the way that s3-fuse translates calls requires the entire bucket content to be listed, but didn't do much investigation beyond that.

I also tried just mounting a single bucket and using a local OverlayFS layer, with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know exactly what you want, by the way, our self-maintained s3 server like amazon s3(oss) is like what you said(a overlay oss).

To satisfy your requirement, the implemented s3 server should have an interface named snapshot. While a bucket is running, we can create a snapshot for it, and then all write on it would like test data, they will be deleted after some time.

But sorry there is not any opensource s3 server can provide a interface named snapshot(copy on write), but we can start one minio server on a rbd volume, create snapshot when you need and after testing, you can remove the snapshot...